# NSOperationQueue and UITableView release is crashing my app

Tags: objective-c, ios, exc-bad-access, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

This is by far the weirdest problem I've been stuck with.

I have a UIViewController on a UINavigationController and I want to call a method at viewDidAppear using NSInvocationOperation so it can run on a back thread when the view becomes visible.

The problem is that if I pop the view controller *BEFORE* the operation (in this case the *testMethod* method) completes running, the app crashes.

Everything works fine if I pop the view controller *AFTER* the operation runs it's course.

When the app crashes, it stops at [super dealloc] with "EXC-BAD-ACCESS" and gives me the following error.

> bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), xxxxxxxxx: Tried to obtain the web lock
>   from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may
>   be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing
>   now...

And this is my code (super simplified)..

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
     [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    NSInvocationOperation *theOperation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(testMethod) object:nil];
    [operationQueue addOperation:theOperation];
    [theOperation release];
}

- (void)testMethod
{
    NSLog(@"do some stuff that takes a few seconds to complete");
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_tableView release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

The *testMethod* has some code that takes a few seconds to complete. I only have a few clues and I really don't know how and where to start debugging this.

- Clue #1: The funniest thing is that if I remove the [_tableView release]; from dealloc then the app doesn't crash. But of course this would cause a leak and I can't remove it.
- Clue #2: I've tested this code on a separate "clean" UIViewController with a UITableView and to my surprise it *didn't* crash.
- Clue #3: The app doesn't crash is the UITableView's datasource is set to nil in viewDidLoad.
- Clue #4: The app doesn't seem crash if I use the same code in viewDidAppear somewhere else like an IBAction.
- Clue #5: I've tried looking over stack data with NSZombie but it gives me tons of data and it leads me nowhere.

I have some very complicated code within my UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource and I really don't know where to start debugging this. I really hope I don't have to go through line by line or rewrite the entire thing because of this.

Any pointers on where I should be looking?

Comment: Are you accessing your view controller anywhere within testMethod (e.g. by calling any method on self)? That would explain the crash because when you pop the view controller, it (probably) gets released but the operation still references the dangling pointer.

Comment: I've tried emptying testMethod and delayed it from running for 5 seconds to test if it was anything in the method that was causing it but even a simple NSLog will crash the app consistently.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about this because the documentation on `NSInvocation` is a bit unclear, but it seems to me that the invocation doesn't retain its target (your view controller) which would be a problem here because it tries to call `testMethod` after it's released.

Comment: You could try to retain self when you add the operation and balance it with a release when it's finished. – Or use an `NSBlockOperation`.

Comment: adding [self retain] to testMethod and adding [self release] to dealloc also seems to work, only I feel nervous about leaks and over releasing. Jason's fix seems to work very well. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is likely that your view controller's last reference *is* the operation queue holding onto it, which means you are technically calling (or having the system call) some UIKit methods in a background thread (a big no-no) when the operation cleans up.

To prevent this from happening, you need to send a keep-alive message to your controller on the main thread at the end of your operation, by adding something like this to the last line in your `testMethod`:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(description) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

There is still a chance that this message may get processed before the operation queue releases your view controller, but that chance is pretty remote. If it's still happening, you could do something like this:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(keepAlive:) 
                       withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]
                    waitUntilDone:NO];

- (void)keepAlive:(NSNumber *)fromBackground
{
    if (fromBackground)
         [self performSelector:@selector(keepAlive:) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
}
```

By sending a message to your view controller on the main thread, it will keep the object alive (NSObject retains your view controller until the main thread handles the message). It will also keep the view controller alive if you perform a selector after a delay.

Comment: OMG you are a life saver! I've been up 5 HOURS trying to fix this. THANK YOU!!! I can finally go to sleep now. :D

Comment: I had to use the keepAlive method. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You're crashing because the controller is still trying to use your tableView reference and since you poped the viewController, everything will go away in the dealloc and the tableView is still populating itself. 
You can try asking in your dealloc method if your operation is still running, so you can cancel it and the everything should be fine.

> Once you add an operation to a queue, the operation is out of your
>   hands. The queue takes over and handles the scheduling of that task.
>   However, if you decide later that you do not want to execute the
>   operation after all—because the user pressed a cancel button in a
>   progress panel or quit the application, for example—you can cancel the
>   operation to prevent it from consuming CPU time needlessly. You do
>   this by calling the cancel method of the operation object itself or by
>   calling the cancelAllOperations method of the NSOperationQueue class.
>
> Cancelling an operation does not immediately force it to stop what it
>   is doing. Although respecting the value returned by the isCancelled is
>   expected of all operations, your code must explicitly check the value
>   returned by this method and abort as needed. The default
>   implementation of NSOperation does include checks for cancellation.
>   For example, if you cancel an operation before its start method is
>   called, the start method exits without starting the task.

Comment: I didn't add it to my question but I do have a [operationQueue cancelAllOperations]; in my dealloc. But I understand that calling cancelAllOperations will only cancel queued operations that haven't started yet and doesn't effect operations that are already running. Is there a way to kill a thread or determine if the currently running thread is NOT the main thread?

Comment: Lol I didn't check your exception but you're going so against the Apple GUI ... UIKit objects are NOT thread safe, so you can't call a tableView's reloadData on a background thread, try calling the reloadData in the main thread instead of operations and it should be fine

Comment: I'm not calling anything that manipulates the UITable in the background thread. :S testMethod just runs an HTTP request that takes some time and will sometimes keep running after the view controller has been popped.

Comment: Then it should be your delegate response that is trying to do something with deallocated objects