# Asynchronously loading sound resources in viewDidLoad crashes

Tags: ios, multithreading, uiviewcontroller, exc-bad-access, nsblockoperation

All,

I am attempting to load a set of sounds asynchronously when I load a UIViewController. At about the same time, I am (occasionally) also placing a UIView on the top of my ViewController's hierarchy to present a help overlay. When I do this, the app crashes with a bad exec. If the view is not added, the app does not crash. My ViewController looks something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    __soundHelper = [[SoundHelper alloc] initWithSounds];

    // Other stuff
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
    // ****** Set up the Help Screen
    self.coachMarkView = [[FHSCoachMarkView alloc] initWithImageName:@"help_GradingVC" 
                                                    coveringView:self.view 
                                                     withOpacity:0.9 
                                                    dismissOnTap:YES 
                                                    withDelegate:self];

    [self.coachMarkView showCoachMarkView];
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
```

The main asynchronous loading method of `SoundHelper` (called from 'initWithSounds') looks like this:

```
// Helper method that loads sounds as needed
- (void)loadSounds {

    // Run this loading code in a separate thread
    NSOperationQueue *operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    NSBlockOperation *loadSoundsOp = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        // Find all sound files (*.caf) in resource bundles
        __soundCache = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithCapacity:0];

        NSString * sndFileName;
        NSArray *soundFiles = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:STR_SOUND_EXT inDirectory:nil];

        // Loop through all of the sounds found
        for (NSString * soundFileNamePath in soundFiles) {
            // Add the sound file to the dictionary
            sndFileName = [[soundFileNamePath lastPathComponent] lowercaseString];
            [__soundCache setObject:[self soundPath:soundFileNamePath] forKey:sndFileName];
        }

        // From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334647/nsoperationqueue-and-uitableview-release-is-crashing-my-app
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(description) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
    }];
    [operationQueue addOperation:loadSoundsOp];
}
```

The crash seems to occur when the block exits. The `init` of `FHSCoachMarkView` looks like this:

```
- (FHSCoachMarkView *)initWithImageName:(NSString *) imageName 
                           coveringView:(UIView *) view
                            withOpacity:(CGFloat) opacity
                           dismissOnTap:(BOOL) dismissOnTap
                           withDelegate:(id<FHSCoachMarkViewDelegate>) delegateID
{
    // Reset Viewed Coach Marks if User Setting is set to show them
    [self resetSettings];

    __coveringView = view;        
    self = [super initWithFrame:__coveringView.frame];
    if (self) {
        // Record the string for later reference
        __coachMarkName = [NSString stringWithString:imageName];
        self.delegate = delegateID;

        UIImage * image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imageName ofType:@"png"]];

        // ****** Configure the View Hierarchy
        UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

        [self addSubview:imgView];
        [__coveringView.superview insertSubview:self aboveSubview:__coveringView];

        // ****** Configure the View Hierarchy with the proper opacity
        __coachMarkViewOpacity = opacity;
        self.hidden = YES;
        self.opaque = NO;
        self.alpha = __coachMarkViewOpacity;

        imgView.hidden = NO;
        imgView.opaque = NO;
        imgView.alpha = __coachMarkViewOpacity;

        // ****** Configure whether the coachMark can be dismissed when it's body is tapped
        __dismissOnTap = dismissOnTap;

        // If it is dismissable, set up a gesture recognizer
        if (__dismissOnTap) {
            UITapGestureRecognizer * tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                                                                      action:@selector(coachMarkWasTapped:)];
            [self addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

I have tried invoking the asynchronous block using both `NSBlockOperation` and `dispatch_async` and both have had the same results. Additionally, I've removed the aysnch call altogether and loaded the sounds on the main thread. That works fine. I also tried the solution suggested by @Jason in: [NSOperationQueue and UITableView release is crashing my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334647/nsoperationqueue-and-uitableview-release-is-crashing-my-app) but the same thing happened there too.

Is this actually an issue with the view being added in FHSCoachMarkView, or is it possibly related to the fact that both access `mainBundle`? I'm a bit new to asynch coding in iOS, so I'm at a bit of a loss. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out: I had set up a listener on the `SoundHelper` object (`NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification`) that listened for when NSUserDefaults were changed, and loaded the sounds if the user defaults indicated so. The `FHSCoachMarkView` was also making changes to `NSUserDefaults`. In the `SoundHelper`, I was not properly checking which defaults were being changed, so the asynch sound loading method was being called each time a change was made. So multiple threads were attempting to modify the `__soundCache` instance variable. it didn't seem to like that.

Question: Is this the correct way to answer your own question? Or should I have just added a comment to the question it self?

Thanks.